# Is it safe to install old libraries? Wine issue

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries

I'm trying to run Medal of Honor Allied Assault on my xubuntu 14.04 box. Yet, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There is a solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350773/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libstdc-so-5). Yet, I'm not sure it is safe to install them. Also, my system is 64-bit, whereas the libraries needed are for 32-bit (according to that post). Is it safe to proceed?

Note: I've looked in my `/usr/lib/` folder and there is no such library, not even for newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try installing the 64 bit version to see if that will resolve the problem. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
```

Please post any more errors.

**EDIT**:

Okay, then install the i386 version like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

Please post any more errors.

Comment: Done. Installed amd64 version automatically, but error persist. In fact, the library is not in `/usr/lib/`, even after installation!

Comment: @luchonacho that file is found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5

Comment: @luchonacho I have updated the instructions

Comment: @luchonacho please let me know if you get an error trying to install that i386 version as you may need to add the foreign arch to dpkg.

Comment: I had to add a shared link to `usr/lib/`. Then I got `libstdc++.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`.  Then I installed 32-bit version, and it worked! I feel this turned into how to run MOHAA under linux, which was my ultimate goal. Thanks for that! But still, just to learn, is it always safe to install any library from repositories?

Comment: @luchonacho Yes, it is usually safe. You will always be provided a summary of the changes to be made and it is always wise to review these changes before accepting them. When it is not safe, you will see a list of packages to be REMOVED, that is when you should abort an installation. If this answers your question, don't forget to click the icon to the left, thanks!